# Adding 2 hours in ArcMap's field calculator using Python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python

I am trying to add 2 hours from a particular time, but I do not want to end up with 13:00. I isolated the hour in its own field so the minutes would not be a problem. I am not sure what I am missing. I have switched up the syntax by adding and removing the colons and also capitalizing "if" and "else."

Essentially I just don't want 11am become 13pm instead of 1pm.

I am using the calculate field tool in ArcGIS for Desktop 10.5.1.

```
if (int(!LT_Hour!) + 2) >12
   x = 1
else
   x = (int(!LT_Hour!)+2)
end if
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a reason to use a proper datetime type. Do the math in the datetime column, then format the result after.  Otherwise you have to reinvent the wheel with multiple columns of input and output, to handle rollover properly

Comment: Ultimately, that is what I am doing. At this stage in my field calculations I am trying to get the hour part correct. Next, I am going to append the rest of the data to this new hour calculation. I just didn't want to end up with military time. I am also not used to using Python in field calculator, but this is much easier than using search cursors in a pure python environment.

Comment: unrelated to your actual code, the format of your field calculator equation won't work. Check the ESRI help for how to format your expression and code block with python. [Calculate Field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_11EAB368A53B4D1C9618A58A1B09F9D0)

Answer (score 2):

you can convert military time to a 12 hour clock by subtracting 12 from the military time.
You can try something like this, but as people have commented, perhaps using a datetime data-type would be a cleaner approach.

```
if (int(!LT_Hour!) + 2) >12:   
   x = (int(!LT_Hour!) + 2) - 12
else:
   x = (int(!LT_Hour!)+2)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Marshall. I ran your script and it was still giving me syntax errors. I switched to VBA to tweak the input field, and I realized I was missing the "Then."

My final VBA code is below. It is essentially the same as the Python code @Marshall states.

```
If( [LT_Hour] + 2) >12 Then
 x = ([LT_Hour] + 2) - 12
Else
x = ([LT_Hour]+2)
end if
```